# The sum of distances from the sides of a regular polygon to an interior point is a constant

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons

Let there be a regular polygon of $n$ sides. Assume there is a point $P$ inside the polygon, then prove that

> $$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots + a_n= \text{constant}$$
>   where $a_i$ is the distance of the point from the $i$-th side.

Please help as soon as possible.....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani's_theorem

Comment: It is trivial for $n$ even (because opposite sides are parallel).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks a lot for the answer......

Comment: @almagest I don't think it would be trivial for and even number of sides, because if you take a polygon of even sides(assume we take a square) then also Viviani's theorem holds true and the the sum of the distances comes out as constant....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area of the triangle formed by the point and the $i$-th side is proportional to $a_i$. These areas add up to the area of the polygon, so the $a_i$ also add up to a constant (the area over half the side length).

Comment: Thanks @joriki for the answer....